# Calculating The Average Amplitude of an Audio File Using FFT in Javascript

Tags: javascript, audio, signal-processing, fft

I am currently involved in a project in which I want to find the average amplitude for given audio data in any given AAC file. I am currently reading the file as an array buffer and passing into an Uint8Array.

```
var dataArray = new Uint8Array(buffer)
```

Then I set up two arrays, one real(containing the audio data) and one imaginary(containing all zeros), and pass them into an FFT. The audio data is then placed into a new array such that the numbers within the array are no longer treated as unsigned 8-bit integers.

```
var realArray = [audio data here]
var imagArray = [0,0,0,0,0,0,...]
transform(realArray, imagArray)
```

I then go through the arrays, looping from 0 to N/2, where N is the size of the initial buffer containing the raw audio data, and calculate the magnitude of each frequency bin. Finally, I divide the sum of these magnitudes by N/2.

The problem is that on some occasions, for audio played at a lower intensity, I get a high value compared to the value given by audio played at a higher intensity. Is my approach correct in relation to achieving my goal or is there a better way of going about it? Thanks.

Note: For those interested the FFT being used can be found here in several languages. [FFT](http://www.nayuki.io/page/free-small-fft-in-multiple-languages)
I am passing the middle 2^20 bytes of the audio file into the FFT then doing my calculations.

Comment: Is `dataArray` the AAC data read directly or did you first decode it to PCM?

Comment: It is read directly. I don't know what PCM is.

Comment: I think the point that jaket is making is that the [AAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Audio_Coding) file data needs to be decompressed/decoded to get actual audio sample values ([PCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation)) - you can't just use the raw bytes that you've read from the file.

Comment: Oh ok. I assumed that I could just use the raw bytes. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: So I'm decoding the audio data and then I'm splitting the decoded audio into its two channels. I'm confused as to how I'd go about finding the average amplitude after having the separate channel data.

Comment: The amplitude for each channel will probably be very similar if you're looking at a long-ish time window - you could just calculate the RMS for each channel though, and then take the mean or the max of these two RMS channel amplitudes, depending on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Just curious. But why is the RMS preferred rather than a normal average.

Comment: Various reasons, but audio signals ten to have both positive and negative values (think about a sine wave), so a straight average would give you 0 (or a residual DC component) and would not tell you anything about the signal power. RMS however is directly related to power (remember `W = V^2/R`).

Comment: Yeah, I definitely noticed very small values(about 5 decimals) when using a regular average. Thanks for the help

Comment: I'd imagine the file will have a very uniform amplitude because it's an entropy encoded file.  You will need to decompress it first to obtain PCM samples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really don't need to use an FFT for this - [Parseval's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem) essentially means that energy in the time domain is equal to energy in the frequency domain, so the FFT part is redundant - you can just calculate amplitude in the time domain. Typically this is done by calculating the [RMS value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) of the signal over a chosen time window (the length of this time window depends on what you are trying to achieve).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll implement it this way.